# SSIS - How to process one row at a time

Tags: ssis

Destination table has 1 row already existing with IsCurrent = 1 
Data source returns 2 rows
I want to process one row at a time 
so for 1st row Do lookup and set IsCurrent to 1 and set IsCurrent for already existing row to 0
Then I want to repeat this for 2nd row
so at the end I have 3 rows and 3rd row has IsCurrent to 1 and other two are set to 0

But since both the rows get processed at same time I am unable to do above.

I could do this using script task but I was hoping if there is an easier way to do it.

Trying to do SCD without using SSIS SCD transformation

Comment: Is "trying to do SCD without SCD transformation" your real issue? Have you checked out this component: https://dimensionmergescd.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to this one row at a time. Avoid cursors or cursory approach.

Based on your SSIS package you can do it something like this in execute sql task.

**Step 1:** Update Destination table

```
UPDATE D
 SET isCurrent = 0
  FROM DestinationTable D
  JOIN SourceTable S
    ON D.LookupField = S.LookupField
```

**Step 2:** Insert new rows in Destination Table

```
INSERT INTO D
  SELECT ... 
   FROM Source 
   JOIN .....
   WHERE .....
```

Based on the flavor or SQL Server you are using you can use Upsert (`Merge`) Statement to do update and insert at the same time.

Other things you need to consider is : 
1. What if your destination table has more than 1 rows. How do you want to handle it. 
2. What if your destination table has no matching rows.

Based on the answers of above 2 you might need to update your SSIS package to handle such conditions.

Answer (score 0):

In SSIS, as part of the data flow the OLE DB Destination Component is used to insert records into a table in a SQL Server database. There quite a few strategies that can be adopted while loading data into a table.
In the OLEDB Destination Component properties there are different AccessMode, one of them is called OpenRowSet Using Fast Load option. When this option is set one gets to work with other FastLoad Properties such as:

FastLoadKeepIdentity
FastLoadKeepNulls
FastLoadOptions
FastLoadMaxInsertCommitSize

When doing a Fastload, the FastLoadMaxInsertCommitSize is Set to 0, this means that the insert into a table is done has one transaction and then a Commit is applied for the transaction. The reason why this value has to be managed is because when the number of rows being inserted are huge (say a million/millions), it would be wise to break up the transaction into a smaller number of rows per insert. The other reason for having smaller transactions is also being able to manage the log effectively.